# Prolog how to find all coordinates in format "X/Y" on a N by N grid

Tags: prolog

I've seen a lot of tutorials that ask similar questions, but the problem I'm having is that our instructor wants us to represent our coordinates using variables of the exact form "X/Y", with that slash in the middle, and I'm not sure how to map a online example of how to map code like `numlist(1,N,ListToGenerate).` into this format.

So, as a concrete example, I want to know, **how do I create a list where the values run from 1/1 to N/N**, and more abstractly, **what do you even call variables in this format?** They aren't tuples and they aren't 2-element lists… I want to call them compound variables, but I'm not sure if that's correct either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are ever unsure about what a term "actually" is, use **`write_canonical/1`** to obtain the **canonical** representation of the term.

For example:

```
?- write_canonical(a/b).
/(a,b)
```

So, you see: A term of the form `X/Y` *is* the term `/(X,Y)`, that is, like *any other **compound term***. In this concrete case, the functor is `/`, which is also an **infix operator** so that you can use infix notation in addition to functional notation. What you call "tuples" are *also* compound terms. In fact, Prolog has no "tuples".

You construct such terms in exactly the same way as all other terms: You can either write them down *directly*, as in `[1/1,1/2,1/3,...]` *or* describe them via predicates.

In your specific case, an *all-solution* predicate like **`findall/3`** may help you to collect all solutions of `between/3` into a list:

`findall(X/Y, ..., List)`

where I leave the `...` part as a challenge.

Comment: I think I've mostly figured this out. The command "findall(X/Y, between(1,8,X), List)." gives me a list with all the x values bound but the y values unknown, yet "findall(X/Y, between(1,8,X/Y), List)." gives me a typeerror. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You're almost there. `findall(X/Y, (between(1, 8, X), between(1, 8, Y)), List).` will do what you want. (Note the parentheses.) As such composite goals become big, hard to read, and boring to understand if they contain temporary variables, I'd recommend factoring it out to a predicate `coordinate(X/Y) :- ...` and using `findall/3` on that.